# How to calculate the angle between matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand the formula:
$cos\left(θ\right)=\frac{tr\left(AB^T\right)}{\sqrt{tr\left(AA^T\right)\cdot tr\left(BB^T\right)}}$
Only one thing is not clear to me,the number I get is the angle itself?
Or the number should be obtained by the cos function?
I will give an example with simple numbers to make the question clearer.
$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix} B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&2\end{pmatrix}$
$\frac{tr\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&2\end{pmatrix}^t\right)}{\sqrt{tr\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}^t\right)\cdot tr\left(\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&2\end{pmatrix}^t\right)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
So the angle is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\approx 0.577)$ or $cos (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})\approx 0.837$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. With $\theta$ your angle, you have $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and so $\theta = 2 \pi n \pm \arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$, where $\arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \approx 0.955$ (radians).

Comment: Where does the formula come from? and how does n relate to the formula?

Comment: The formula is just exactly the formula that you gave me. The $n$ is just there because there are multiple solutions to $\cos \theta = x$ for any $x$ in $[-1,1]$ (there are two in each interval of length $2\pi$, unless $x = 1$ or $x = -1$, in whch case there is only one for each). Geometrically, that translates to rotating from $A$ to $B$ vs rotating from $B$ to $A$ for the angles in each interval (the $\pm$ above), and "going around the circle" $n$ times beforehand (therefore not actually going anywhere) for the $2\pi n$ offset.

Comment: So if I understand correctly $  arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\right)$  that's the answer? (If I have no reason to consider the number of rounds)

Comment: Except that you've replaced $\sqrt{3}$ with $\sqrt{13}$, and assuming that you want the unsigned angle (so you don't care if it's clockwise or anticlockwise), yes.